# pure-ftpd "Error in the pull function" for some clients

Tags: ftp

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 running pure-ftpd 1.0.46 configured as follows:

```
AltLog clf:/var/log/pure-ftpd/transfer.log
Daemonize yes
FSCharset UTF-8
PAMAuthentication no
TLS 1
VerboseLog yes
ChrootEveryone yes
DisplayDotFiles yes
MinUID 30 
PassivePortRange 12000 13000
TLSCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:+TLSv1:!SSLv2:+SSLv3
CustomerProof yes
ForcePassiveIP 185.73.xx.xx
NoAnonymous yes
PureDB /etc/pure-ftpd/pureftpd.pdb
UnixAuthentication no
```

The passive port range (TCP) is open on the firewall, and our ISP confirms there is no NATing or other network configuration upstream.

Using (for example) GNU ftp client, the server accepts plain FTP no problem in tests from outside our network.

However, we have been getting reports of some clients unable to connect with various errors such as timeouts. A test on https://ftptest.net confirms the following (in explicit TLS mode, but also in other modes:

```
Command: CLNT https://ftptest.net on behalf of 88.202.156.157
Reply: 530 You aren't logged in
Command: AUTH TLS
Reply: 234 AUTH TLS OK.
Status: Performing TLS handshake...
Status: TLS handshake successful, verifying certificate...
Status: Received 1 certificates from server.

Status: cert[0]: [cert info here]
Command: USER oddjob
Error: Could not read from socket: Error in the pull function.
```

Does anyone know where to start in diagnosing this?

**EDIT**

In implicit mode, the error from ftptest looks like this:

```
Status: Connecting to 2001:ba8:0:xxxxx
Status: Connected, performing TLS handshake...
Error: TLS handshake failed: An unexpected TLS packet was received.
```

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm running into the same issue

Comment: Nope. Not a clue. I think I might try setting a bounty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there's an issue with the pure-ftpd 1.0.46 and OpenSSL 1.1.1, but Ubuntu 18.04 hasn't gotten an updated pure-ftpd package. If you manually download the 1.0.47 package and install it, it should solve your problem. It worked for me, at least.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pure-ftpd/+bug/1832998/

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pure-ftpd/+bug/1832998/comments/8